# Using Angular or Ionic, how can I exclude a string from being looped?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am building an app using Ionic and Angular. Using Ionic's grid layout, I have the following code as per design layout given below :

[image]

```
<div id ="neededfoodnames" *ngFor="let list of lists; let i = index">

  <ion-item (click)="togglefoods(list.category)" *ngIf="lists[i-1]?.category != list.category" class="categoryList">
    {{list.category}}
    <ion-icon item-right name="arrow-forward" *ngIf="list.category != currentCategory"></ion-icon>
    <ion-icon item-right name="arrow-down" *ngIf="list.category == currentCategory"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>

<div class="foodList" *ngIf="list.category == currentCategory" (click)="unlist(list)">
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          We Need
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="offFoods">
          {{list.foodname}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col  class="onFoods">
          {{list.foodname}}
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</div>
</div>
```

However, the text "We Need" is shown every time a new list.foodname is being pulled from the database. How can I keep this text and only have it display once?

Comment: Just put it outside of the `ngFor`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="foodList">
  <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
         We Need
      </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-grid *ngIf="list.category == currentCategory" (click)="unlist(list)">

    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="offFoods">
        {{list.foodname}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col  class="onFoods">
        {{list.foodname}}
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</div>
```

try this one. This will unlist the ion-grids always. U will get list of grids.
or you have to move the 'we need' outside of the foodlist

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trick using `ngIf` to show the text once.

```
<ion-grid>
   <ion-row *ngIf="i == 0">
      <ion-col>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
         We Need
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
   <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="offFoods">
         {{list.foodname}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col  class="onFoods">
         {{list.foodname}}
      </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

it may be better to do the data handling in the TS code using

```
this.lists =  this.lists.filter(item=>{
return item != ....})
```

This for better readibility, code handling and testing

Besides the question why "We need" is string that fits in a collection of foodnames.

Regards

Tom